# exporting database file in excel using php

Tags: php, excel

below is my code for exporting my database to excel using php. its working but its giving a wrong output. it doesn't  give the output of my database but instead the html design/script only. how can i solve this problem? any help please. thanks.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['download']))

{

$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "copylandia";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dataname = "web-ata";
$tablename = "user";
$fields="`number`, initial, fname, lname, mname, emailadd, username, password, `group`, position, `level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`, `level6`, `level7`";


$datestamp = date("d-m-Y");
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass) or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbname);

$query = ("select $fields from $tablename");
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

$myarray = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM))
{
$myarray[] = implode("\t", $row);
}

$myarray = implode("\r\n",$myarray);

$filename = "$dataname.$datestamp.xls";

header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel");

echo $array;
}
?>
```

Comment: You're echoing `$array` - where is that variable set? Also, judging from the name of the variable, it's an array. You can't `echo` an array.

Comment: You have no `<?php` opening tag, so the PHP interpreter never fires up in the first place.

Comment: You said you changed the `echo $array;` to `echo $myarray;`, however like I said you still cannot `echo` an `array`

Comment: Why are you imploding $myarray twice? The first one will give you a single element of string (tab-separated $row elements), and the second probably doesn't do anything, as $myarray was a single element array. And then, $array isn't set. By the way, if this is a one-off job to create a CSV file to import into a spreadsheet, phpMyAdmin will do it directly for you.

Answer (score 0):

Either you've cut out the *only* parts of the script which are relevant to the problem - or you've forgotten to use PHP code delimiter (<?php ...).

Are you invoking the script via a browser and webserver or from the command line? Do PHP scripts normally work on your machine when accessed in this way?

Answer (score -1):

Use some PHP library to create excel file. [phpexcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

In your code you can use like this

```
$filename = "$dataname.$datestamp.xls";

header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type:application/vnd.ms-excel");

echo implode("\r\n",$myarray);
exit;
```

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question.

Comment: @Stanyer That i know suggest a library is not an answer. But it is a better way to create the excelsheets.

Comment: i changed it from "echo $array" to "echo $myarray". but still it has same output of  html design/script.

Comment: This line is fine? $fields="`number`, initial, fname, lname, mname, emailadd, username, password, `group`, position, `level1`, `level2`, `level3`, `level4`, `level5`, `level6`, `level7`";

Comment: please print the result after the while loop using print_r.